# RubyMine Go To Definition isn't working

Tags: rubymine

I'm having trouble with Rubymine in that I cannot Go to Declaration of files that I once was able to go to before (these aren't dynamic classes or methods). I'm not sure if it's related to the fact that I have some scopes for file coloring or for some other reason, but this feature doesn't seem to be working properly.

The version of RubyMine is 5.4.3.2.1 on Windows. Does anyone know the problem or a solution?

Comment: Have you tried to reproduce your issue in [RubyMine EAP](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/RUBYDEV/RubyMine+EAP)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Did you try?

`File | Invalidate Caches... > Invalidate and Restart`

I had the same problem in the same version, but after invalidating the caches "Go to Declaration" works again.

Comment: This also fixed a problem with Go To File, on version 6.3. Thanks!

Comment: Fixed the problem with Go To File on version 7.0 for me too.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue after updating to 2020.1.2. My project root was removed for some reason. I had to re-add it by doing the below. This was not very obvious...

RubyMine > Preferences > Project Structure > + Add Content Root (path to your project)

Answer (score 0):

My RubyMine was just pointing at the wrong Ruby version where the gems weren't installed. I fixed this by going to `Preferences > Languages and Frameworks > Ruby SDK and Gems` and selecting the Ruby version I bundled my Rails app with.